# When using Entity Framework Code First, is it possible to specify a schema for the many-to-many link table created when not using the fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have two entities:  Recipe and Ingredient.

Entites:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientId{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipies {get;set;}
}

public class Recipe
{
    public int RecipeId{get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients {get;set;}
}
```

My two entities map to their respective tables in the "Web" schema in our database:

```
ToTable( "Recipe", "Web" );
ToTable( "Ingredient", "Web" );
```

... and everything works fine.  The only hiccup is that the generated many-to-many table is created in the "dbo" schema.

`dbo.RecipeIngredients`

Without defining the relationships in the Fluent API, is there a way to specify "Web" as the table schema to use for the many-to-many tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Data annotations support only basic subset of mapping features. If you want to have full code first mapping feature set you must use Fluent API (which is also much cleaner way to define mapping). Defining anything related to junction table is considered as advanced mapping feature and it is currently available only in Fluent API.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The extra 10 minutes it took me to define all my mappings wasn't so bad after all.